# how to record last visit page on Eclipse RAP develop

Tags: eclipse-rap

In the development of RAP eclipse, I want to record the last visit of the page, and the next time to open the application is the last visit to the page.
which API I need to use the RAP eclipse to develop ？

Comment: What exactly do you want to record - the time the application has been accessed? The state or the layout of the UI? When you say "the page" - do you refer to a view or a tab in the UI, ot the entire HTML page in the browser that contains the RAP application?

Comment: @falfstx it's a status of my application at last visited. the problem is ,every time i refresh my rap application returns to the home page,but i want to stay with my page before i refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it's only about reloading the application, the [BrowserNavigation](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=navigation.html&version=2.3) might help. For example, this [online demo](http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demo/release/rapdemo/) uses this service to set an entry into the browser history for every page that is opened. When you select a page in the menu and then reload, the application will load the same page. This demo is part of the RAP project, you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/rap/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.rap.examples/src/org/eclipse/rap/examples/internal/MainUi.java).

If this solution is not sufficient, the RAP Developer's Guide also contains introduction to [storing data](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=data-stores.html&version=2.3) in a RAP application.

Comment: @relfstx,i feel i can't create a master-details pages like rcp platform,and i don't found any demo in rap website,can you give me some guide,or a demo please

Comment: @wykCN Do you have an example of what you're trying to build?

Comment: i have no example it just a demand from my boss, i use a tree and a table completed . thanks ! :D

Comment: It's hard to recommend something without understanding what you're trying to build. I think you should explain your requirements in more detail in a new question like "How to Implement a Master Details UI in RAP".